# Process code lines with in specific pattern boundary from text file separately?

Tags: shell, awk

I have used this script to extract all the occurences of function data between name __libc_memalign and : from "file1" to "file 2" . Now the file 2 contains multiple(6000 group) occurrences of code with in this  pattern. How I can iterate through each group in the file "file2" and process each group?

```
`awk '/__libc_memalign/ {p=1;print;next}  /:/ && p {p=0;print} p' file1.out >file2`
```

sample input

```
        0   0xc40840    :   __libc_memalign
    0   0x40bac0    0x7ffe493d0d50  W
    0   0x40bac2    0x7ffe493d0d48  W
    0   0x40bac4    0x7ffe493d0d40  W
..
     0  0xc40840    :   __libc_memalign
        0   0x40bac0    0x7ffe493d0d50  R
        0   0x40bac2    0x7ffe493d0d48  R
        0   0x40bac4    0x7ffe493d0d40  R
....
    0   0xc40840    :   __libc_memalign
        0   0x40bab0    0x7ffe493b0d50  W
        0   0x40bab2    0x7ffe493dbd48  R
        0   0x40bac4    0x7ffe493d0d40  W
```

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? Is each line in `file2` a "group"? `while read -r group; do process "$group"; done <file2`

Comment: between pattern there are say 50 lines  .. i want to process those fifty lines as a group (may be redirected to some other file) ..perform some operations .. then  copy next fifty  lines to the same file  ...do process .. go on .. till all 6000 such groups are over

Comment: The Awk variable `file1` doesn't seem to be defined, where does `print > file1` put its output?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you mean by "group" or "process" but hopefully at least this could nudge you in the right direction.

Assuming there are no empty lines in your groups, add a separator between them; then loop over sequences between empty lines.  Your Awk script already seems to put an empty line when it finishes a group, so you can simply

```
awk '/__libc_memalign/ {p=1; print; next}
    /:/ && p {p=0; print} p' file1.out |
while true; do
    while read -r line; do
        case $line in '') break;; esac
        echo "$line"
    done |
    # Pipe the collected group into "process
    process
done
```

This is fairly clumsy, and can probably be refactored significantly.  If you don't particularly need the intermediate results, maybe simply

```
awk '/__libc_memalign/ {
        p=1; cmd = "process" print | cmd; next}
    /:/ && p { p=0; close(cmd) }
    p { print | cmd }' file1.out
```

Comment: In the sample input last column is Ws and Rs. In th first GROUP, number of Ws is 3 .For the next GROUP number of Ws is 0, for the Last  GROUP number of Ws is  2.  .calculating number of Ws in each group is the PROCESS

Comment: Why are you not doing that in Awk directly then? I would suggest you ask a new question with your actual requirements and accept this answer (or post an answer of your own and accept that; or delete this question entirely, but realize that *repeatedly* deleting your questions is going to be flagged as potentially abusive).

Comment: `awk '/__libc_memalign/ { if (hits) print hits "/" lines; p=1; hits = lines = 0 } p && $NF ~ /^[WR]$/ { if ($NF == "W") hits ++; lines++ } /:/ { p = 0 } END { if (hits) print hits "/" lines }' file1.out`